# Unable to read third child in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a ListView which will read the data from firebase.
Structure of my realtime database is

databaase-d2b83

----- Categories

---------- Fruits

--------------- apple:101

---------- Veggies

----------------onions:102

----------------tomato:103

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView ;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase ;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference ;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList ;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter ;
    String string , val = "Categories" ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>() ;
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this , R.layout.listcategories , R.id.textView , arrayList) ;

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list) ;
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() ;
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference() ;
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    string = ds.getKey().toString() ;
                    arrayList.add(string) ;

                }
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }) ;
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                val = ((TextView)view).getText().toString() ;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                arrayList.clear();
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



               databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(val) ;
               databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot1.getChildren())
                           arrayList.add(ds.getKey()) ;




                       listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

               }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               });


            }
        });
    }

}
```

When i run the app it shows up-to second child i.e. "Veggies" . When setOnItemClickListener() is called for either of second child (Fruits or Veggies) then no next child is obtained. Also at this point the getChildernCount() for "dataSnapshot" becomes zero.

Comment: If your data is likely to change during the time it is in the list, perhaps from a network call or an update from Firebase, it is recommended to follow the View-Holder pattern with a RecyclerView.

Comment: Even if i use a RecyclerView I wont access the childs of "Fruits" or "Veggies"

Comment: I know. I was just trying to tell you that that is generally better practice.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?